Convert the following measurement timestamps to uniform timestamp
I have a .csv file where many different properties are measured with 10 Hz frequency. The first row with the timestamps looks as follows:
0                     NaN
1        29/07/2021 11:00 
2                 00:00.1 
3                 00:00.2 
4                 00:00.3 
5                 00:00.4 
6                 00:00.5 
7                 00:00.6 
8                 00:00.7 
9                 00:00.8 
10                00:00.9 
11       29/07/2021 11:00 
12                00:01.1 
13                00:01.2 
14                00:01.3 
                    ...

Name: TIMESTAMP, Length: 36601, dtype: object

I have never seen data being recorded like that. Is there a way to convert all the rows with given milliseconds to a datetime format as in row 1 but with ms and add ms to the rows 1, 11 and so on? So that I have:
0                     NaN
1        29/07/2021 11:00:00.1 
2        29/07/2021 11:00:00.2
3        29/07/2021 11:00:00.3
                      ...


data = pd.read_csv('file.csv', skiprows=1, header=None, names=['timestamp'])

absolute_timestamps = []

base_time = None

for index, row in data.iterrows():
    timestamp = row['timestamp']
    
    if isinstance(timestamp, float):
        continue
    
    if '/' in timestamp:
        base_time = datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
        current_time = base_time
    else:
        try:
            seconds, milliseconds = map(float, timestamp.split(':'))
            delta = timedelta(seconds=seconds, milliseconds=milliseconds*100)
            current_time = base_time + delta

            absolute_timestamps.append(current_time)
        except ValueError:
            continue

result_df = pd.DataFrame(absolute_timestamps, columns=['absolute_timestamp'])

print(result_df)

This is giving me an empty DataFrame.
MRE of the csv file:
TIMESTAMP,Ux,Uy,Uz,Ts,CO2,H2O,press,t_hmp,e_hmp,rh_hmp
,m/s,m/s,m/s,C,mg/m^3,g/m^3,kPa,C,kPa,percent
29/07/2021 11:00,0.241,-0.2965,0.258,25.99887,675.759,15.90253,98.67521,27.66419,2.129122,57.44878
00:00.1,0.3545,-0.34425,0.21125,25.87463,675.9955,15.9117,98.65817,27.66253,2.136629,57.65696
00:00.2,0.38175,-0.28125,0.2045,25.95746,675.7098,15.93659,98.65817,27.65421,2.137441,57.70692
00:00.3,0.3465,-0.22175,0.20025,26.05753,674.4702,15.98516,98.67521,27.65919,2.137509,57.69193
00:00.4,0.08875,-0.326,0.2305,26.0351,676.1616,15.89104,98.65817,27.67419,2.139629,57.69859
00:00.5,0.012,-0.4945,0.26625,26.00403,675.5728,15.90638,98.65817,27.6925,2.142476,57.71358
00:00.6,0.10225,-0.42525,0.2155,25.9816,670.6963,16.13573,98.67521,27.63588,2.132997,57.64863
00:00.7,0.06425,-0.39075,0.01075,26.0144,671.8867,16.07627,98.69327,27.66419,2.137578,57.67694
00:00.8,0.2435,-0.51875,0.1525,25.98849,668.4075,16.23631,98.65817,27.66419,2.136035,57.6353
00:00.9,0.22075,-0.61475,0.033,25.80215,674.759,15.92974,98.68423,27.62256,2.132384,57.67694
29/07/2021 11:00,0.28025,-0.7262501,-0.053,25.84531,677.9393,15.76822,98.67521,27.65587,2.137896,57.71358
00:01.1,0.27025,-0.7032501,-0.13675,25.83667,679.4952,15.69851,98.65817,27.64421,2.136132,57.70525
00:01.2,0.232,-0.694,-0.05075,25.83496,679.4978,15.70536,98.65817,27.70084,2.145746,57.77353
00:01.3,0.165,-0.6102501,-0.0565,25.86084,679.2551,15.71204,98.67521,27.68085,2.14386,57.79018
00:01.4,0.23975,-0.636,-0.0815,25.82632,679.4276,15.70096,98.64916,27.71249,2.147887,57.79185
00:01.5,0.27175,-0.591,-0.021,25.82806,679.7066,15.69168,98.65817,27.63921,2.137542,57.76021
00:01.6,0.188,-0.60025,-0.04875,25.84009,678.5519,15.75871,98.64916,27.70416,2.145296,57.75022
00:01.7,0.14625,-0.566,0.001,25.80905,680.5561,15.66352,98.67521,27.64587,2.139792,57.79851
00:01.8,0.1705,-0.67675,0.01,25.79874,680.9865,15.64016,98.65817,27.66253,2.141258,57.78186
00:01.9,0.162,-0.6135001,-0.08125,25.7901,681.2719,15.61947,98.69327,27.67252,2.142385,57.77853

Which I want to transform to:
TIMESTAMP,Ux,Uy,Uz,Ts,CO2,H2O,press,t_hmp,e_hmp,rh_hmp
,m/s,m/s,m/s,C,mg/m^3,g/m^3,kPa,C,kPa,percent
29/07/2021 11:00:00.0,0.241,-0.2965,0.258,25.99887,675.759,15.90253,98.67521,27.66419,2.129122,57.44878
29/07/2021 11:00:00.1,0.3545,-0.34425,0.21125,25.87463,675.9955,15.9117,98.65817,27.66253,2.136629,57.65696
29/07/2021 11:00:00.2,0.38175,-0.28125,0.2045,25.95746,675.7098,15.93659,98.65817,27.65421,2.137441,57.70692
29/07/2021 11:00:00.3,0.3465,-0.22175,0.20025,26.05753,674.4702,15.98516,98.67521,27.65919,2.137509,57.69193
29/07/2021 11:00:00.4,0.08875,-0.326,0.2305,26.0351,676.1616,15.89104,98.65817,27.67419,2.139629,57.69859
29/07/2021 11:00:00.5,0.012,-0.4945,0.26625,26.00403,675.5728,15.90638,98.65817,27.6925,2.142476,57.71358
29/07/2021 11:00:00.6,0.10225,-0.42525,0.2155,25.9816,670.6963,16.13573,98.67521,27.63588,2.132997,57.64863
29/07/2021 11:00:00.7,0.06425,-0.39075,0.01075,26.0144,671.8867,16.07627,98.69327,27.66419,2.137578,57.67694
29/07/2021 11:00:00.8,0.2435,-0.51875,0.1525,25.98849,668.4075,16.23631,98.65817,27.66419,2.136035,57.6353
29/07/2021 11:00:00.9,0.22075,-0.61475,0.033,25.80215,674.759,15.92974,98.68423,27.62256,2.132384,57.67694
29/07/2021 11:00:01.0,0.28025,-0.7262501,-0.053,25.84531,677.9393,15.76822,98.67521,27.65587,2.137896,57.71358
29/07/2021 11:00:01.1,0.27025,-0.7032501,-0.13675,25.83667,679.4952,15.69851,98.65817,27.64421,2.136132,57.70525
29/07/2021 11:00:01.2,0.232,-0.694,-0.05075,25.83496,679.4978,15.70536,98.65817,27.70084,2.145746,57.77353
29/07/2021 11:00:01.3,0.165,-0.6102501,-0.0565,25.86084,679.2551,15.71204,98.67521,27.68085,2.14386,57.79018
29/07/2021 11:00:01.4,0.23975,-0.636,-0.0815,25.82632,679.4276,15.70096,98.64916,27.71249,2.147887,57.79185
29/07/2021 11:00:01.5,0.27175,-0.591,-0.021,25.82806,679.7066,15.69168,98.65817,27.63921,2.137542,57.76021
29/07/2021 11:00:01.6,0.188,-0.60025,-0.04875,25.84009,678.5519,15.75871,98.64916,27.70416,2.145296,57.75022
29/07/2021 11:00:01.7,0.14625,-0.566,0.001,25.80905,680.5561,15.66352,98.67521,27.64587,2.139792,57.79851
29/07/2021 11:00:01.8,0.1705,-0.67675,0.01,25.79874,680.9865,15.64016,98.65817,27.66253,2.141258,57.78186
29/07/2021 11:00:01.9,0.162,-0.6135001,-0.08125,25.7901,681.2719,15.61947,98.69327,27.67252,2.142385,57.77853


Why do you continue on those conditions? That will potentially lead to problems updating the dataframe in the event that some rows are skipped.

10 Hz every one minute? is this 00:00.1, 00:01.1 %H:%M.%S or %H:%M.%f https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

Dates are parsed in 3 steps

date to unix timestamp
groupby unix timestamps every 10 records, keeping first as is and adding the rest to the first.
unix timestamps are converted back to datetimes

import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import time

def date_to_unixts(col):
    if len(col.loc[0]) > 7:
        base_time = datetime.strptime(col.loc[0], dt_fmt0)
    else:
        base_time = datetime.strptime(f'01/01/1970 00:{col.loc[0]}', dt_fmt)

    col.loc[0] = base_time.replace(tzinfo = timezone.utc).timestamp()
    return col

def sum_if(x, y):
    # return first
    m = pd.Series([y])
    # add first to rows 1 to 9
    return pd.concat([m, x.iloc[1:].apply(lambda t: t + y)])

pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}'.format

dt_fmt0 = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"
dt_fmt = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f"
data = pd.read_csv('/home/lmc/tmp/temp.csv', skiprows=1, header=None)

# Convert date/time to unix timestamp as is
df = data.apply(date_to_unixts, axis=1)

# add first full date to short dates every 10 records
df['ts2'] = df.groupby(df.index//10)[0].apply(lambda x: sum_if(x, x.iloc[0])).reset_index()[0]
# convert timestamp back to date
df['dt2'] = df['ts2'].apply(lambda y: datetime.utcfromtimestamp(y).strftime(dt_fmt)[:-5])
print(df[[1,2,3,'dt2']])

Result showing a few columns plus parsed datetime
      1     2     3                    dt2
0  0.24 -0.30  0.26  29/07/2021 11:00:00.0
1  0.35 -0.34  0.21  29/07/2021 11:00:00.1
2  0.38 -0.28  0.20  29/07/2021 11:00:00.2
3  0.35 -0.22  0.20  29/07/2021 11:00:00.3
4  0.09 -0.33  0.23  29/07/2021 11:00:00.4
5  0.01 -0.49  0.27  29/07/2021 11:00:00.5
6  0.10 -0.43  0.22  29/07/2021 11:00:00.6
7  0.06 -0.39  0.01  29/07/2021 11:00:00.7
8  0.24 -0.52  0.15  29/07/2021 11:00:00.8
9  0.22 -0.61  0.03  29/07/2021 11:00:00.9
10 0.28 -0.73 -0.05  30/08/2021 17:00:00.0
11 0.27 -0.70 -0.14  30/08/2021 17:00:01.1
12 0.23 -0.69 -0.05  30/08/2021 17:00:01.2
13 0.17 -0.61 -0.06  30/08/2021 17:00:01.3
14 0.24 -0.64 -0.08  30/08/2021 17:00:01.4
15 0.27 -0.59 -0.02  30/08/2021 17:00:01.5
16 0.19 -0.60 -0.05  30/08/2021 17:00:01.6
17 0.15 -0.57  0.00  30/08/2021 17:00:01.7
18 0.17 -0.68  0.01  30/08/2021 17:00:01.8
19 0.16 -0.61 -0.08  30/08/2021 17:00:01.9

Note: Second full date was changed to better identify groups of records.

@juzze I run the answer with the sample you provided except that I changed the date and time of the long dates to make the groups better readable. A thing to look at is pandas version which is 2.2.2 for me (python3.9). The answer should work with your file provided that data is like the provided sample
